# How to configure service fabric load balancer to stop requests to CPU overloaded node?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying to configure service fabric load balancer via this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing

Which Resource Manager Timers should be used to stop requests to CPU overloaded node

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more on whether there is a specific requirement to set this using the Resource Manager. Easier way to do this would be to set the auto scaling option and provide the Threshold CPU usage using the Portal during creating and later getting the Resource Manager template for the same.

Please let me know if this was enough.

Thanks